# Closed-loop position control with a stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, closed-loop

*Disclaimer: I understand this might not be the optimal setup for this application, but this is what I currently have available.*

My controller is connected to:

- a stepper motor with a lead screw for moving a load on a single axis;
- a linear hall sensor for sensing the position of the load over the entire lead screw range.
- an external MPU that is setting the target position.

Controller Requirements:

- The system needs to work under a variable load. the variable load might almost reach the maximum force available from the stepper motor.
- Minimize the settling time of moving from one position to the other.

After looking at the [torque-speed curve](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Basma_Abbas2/publication/318585925/figure/fig5/AS:566307154296837@1512029555137/Torque-vs-Speed-Characteristics-of-a-Stepper-Motor.png) of the stepper motor, these requirements seem to contradict each other: minimizing the settling time requires operating the motor at high speeds, but for getting a high force to overcome the high load, the motor should be operating at low speeds.

(Intuitively, I would say the motor speed should have a proportional error term; and a reciprocal of the error time integral term)

Are there any known feedback equations for this case?
It sounds to me like this problem should be very common, and probably has been discussed in books about servo control.
Are there any books you can recommend addressing this issue?